# Permission to download photo but not add/delete

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, picture-library

For a Photo Library, I want all users to be able to download photos but not add/delete photos. A few users will have full control, but everyone else should only be able to use the photos without changing anything else. I keep trying different permission levels, but I can't get it right. Any ideas on how to basically make it so visitors can download photos (not just right click and save) but not do anything else?

Answer (score 1):

By giving all users read access, they will only be able to download/view photos in the library. You can do this by clicking the cog > Library settings > Permissions for this library, then adding users to either a group with read access or configuring unique permissions if this library needs different permissions to the rest of the site. Here is more information on configuring permissions for a library:

[Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)

Answer (score 1):

As Callum Crowley mentioned, with read access user can:
[image]

Example：
[image]

You can refer this article for more information about User permission:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels